# How do I find the simplest Big O estimate for this function?

Tags: asymptotics

$$r(n) = \Big(\sqrt{n}+20\log_2(n)+n/2\Big)\big(4n+\log(n)+5\big)$$

This was part of my computing science quiz, and I still can't happen to understand how to find the simplest big O estimate.
It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me find the answer to this.

Comment: I've edited your equation (this site uses [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for LaTeX typestting of expresssions).

Comment: Oh yes!! My mistake... Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is Big O for programming so $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

$r(n)=\left(\sqrt{n}+20\log_2(n)+\frac{n}{2}\right)(4n+\log(n)+5)$
$\Longrightarrow r(n)=4n\sqrt{n}+\log(n)\sqrt{n}+5\sqrt{n}+80n\log_2(n)+20\log(n)\log_2(n)+100\log_2(n)+2n^2+\frac{n}{2}\log(n)+\frac{5n}{2}$

Since $\exists c\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\exists N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},~n\ge N_0,~r(n)\le c\cdot n^2\Longrightarrow r(n)\in O(n^2)$.

***Prove:***
$\begin{array}{rclc}
4n\sqrt{n} & \le & 4n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
\log(n)\sqrt{n} & \le & n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
5+\sqrt{n} & \le & 6n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
80n\log_2(n) & \le & 80n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
20\log(n)\log_2(n) & \le & 20n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
100\log_2(n) & \le & 100n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
2n^2 & \le & 2n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
\frac{n}{2}\log(n) & \le & n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
\frac{5n}{2} & \le & 3n^2 & (n\ge1)\\
\Longrightarrow r(n) & \le & 217n^2 & (n\ge1)
\end{array}$

So we can choose $c=217$ and $N_0=1$.

Also, $r(n)\in\Omega(n^2)$, since all functions in the sum are positive for $n\ge1$ then for $c=1$ and $N_0=1$ we have this trivial affirmation: $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:n\ge N_0: c\cdot n^2\le r(n)$.

So $r(n)\in\theta(n^2)$ because $r(n)\in\Omega(n^2)~\wedge~r(n)\in O(n^2)$.

Comment: @TMM What's LHS and RHS?

Comment: Left/right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

We know $\log n=o(\sqrt n)$, $\sqrt n=o(n)$ hence both factors are $O(n)$, and their product is $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Good answer! +1 ... to add some intuition: $n/2$ grows faster than either of $\sqrt{n}$ or $20\log_2(n)$, so the term $n/2$ determines the growth rate of the first factor. Likewise $4n$ determines the growth rate of the second factor.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: I would even say they grow *infinitely* faster, to use a striking phrase.

Comment: @Bernard. Welcome to the club of victims of mysterious downvotes !